# Strange behaviour for loop C++

Tags: c++

I am having trouble understanding why in this code snippet the "Hello" statement is not
being printed. I thought that the condition statement in the for loop starts getting tested after only at the second iteration.

```
  for ( count = 0; count < 0; ++count)
    {
  cout<<"Hello!\n";     
    }
```

Comment: Read this document - http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/

Comment: Zero is small but not less than itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It never enters the loop at all because `for` loops are tested at the start.

You start with `count = 0`, but the loop condition is `count < 0`. So it fails right away and skips the entire loop.

`do-while` loops are the ones that are tested at the end of the iteration.

Answer (score 4):

The `for` loop:

```
for (count = 0; count < 0; ++count)
{
    cout<<"Hello!\n";     
}
```

is defined to be equivalent to:

```
{
    count = 0;
    while (count < 0)
    {
        {
            cout<<"Hello!\n";
        }
        ++count;
    }
}
```

with the caveat that `continue` will go to `++count`, rather than `count < 0`.

Comment: One more set of brackets removes that caveat

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Thanks (fixed)! Anyone who is interested in a less broken version can look at Matthieu M.'s answer too.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought that the condition statement in the for loop starts getting
>   tested after only at the second iteration

No it does not. It is already checked before the first iteration.

Answer (score 2):

The condition is tested first.

A `for` loop

```
 for (<initializer>; <condition>; <increment>) { <body> }
```

is equivalent to:

```
{
  <initializer>
  bool __first = true;
  while ((__first ? __first = false : (<increment>, true)), <condition>) {
    <body>
  }
}
```

The only looping construct that always iterates once is:

```
do {
  <body>
} while (<condition>);
```

Comment: Do you really think that someone who is struggling with `for` loops will be helped by this gratuitous use of the conditional and comma operators?

Comment: @Mankarse: not really, but I guess it will help him appreciate the syntactic sugar that the `for` provides. It may be easier to express it with a `if` followed by a `do/while`.